# Explications with firebase rule for web app

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am building a web applicartion where I can create user, project and where I can attach the project to the user.

I don't understand so much the rules, for the users I did something like thit

```
"rules": {
"people" : {
  "$uid" : {
    ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
  }
}
```

And it works, but when I try to push a project I have a permission denied.

```
"project" : {
    "$uid" : {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
  }

},
```

If anyone have an idea to do this or an example of database rules for complexe relationships between table on Firebase.

Thanks anyone <3

Comment: Can I see some sample data you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have a test user like this

```
people
 qnOelgKeLUM1P8bVe0Q2AJdIPC53
 email:  "test@gmail.com"
 isAdmin:  true
 job:  "Test job"
 nom:  "Test"
 prenom:  "Test"
 profilPicture:  "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nee..."
 username: "Neewd"
 ville: "Paris"
```

And I want to add project to this user (in an array).
So I try to insert the project, get back the ID and update the user.

Comment: Where are your project rules in your rules file? are they parallel to the people rules?